# R: automatically choose model depending on available variables

Tags: r, prediction

Say I have fitted a `lm` model, but I also have all subset models fitted, that is, all `lm` with the list of rhs variables being a subset of the rhs variables of the original `lm`. 
Now, when it comes to prediction. I have a `data.frame` with different missing values in different variables (columns), can you write a script that, for each row, automatically use the fullest possible model for the prediction. So obviously you can't use a model that requires variables which that particular row of data doesn't have.

Example:

```
set.seed(1)
x1=rnorm(10)
x2=rnorm(10)
y=rnorm(10)

lmList=list(lm(y~x1+x2),lm(y~x1),lm(y~x2),lm(y~1))

newdata=data.frame(x1=c(1,1,NA,NA,1),x2=c(1,NA,1,NA,1))
> newdata
  x1 x2
1  1  1
2  1 NA
3 NA  1
4 NA NA
5  1  1
```

What I want is a function `Predict(lmList,newdata=newdata)` so that for row 1 and 5 of the newdata, it uses the first model in the list, for row 2, it uses the second model, for row 3, it uses the thrid model, for row 4, it uses the last model.

Note on any for-loop implementation, there will be cases where multiple rows have the same missing value pattern, e.g. row 1 and 5 in `newdata`. So you might want to bundle those rows together to make it more efficient.

Comment: did you try anything? do you only have two variables and therefore only ever four missing patterns?

Comment: There are a couple of ways to solve this. The easiest is probably to realise that `lm` takes a formula object as its input, and you can make formula objects from strings with `as.formula`, e.g. `lm(as.formula("y ~ x1"))`. You should be able to write something that creates an appropriate string with your dataset.. Edit: or `reformulate(response = "y", "x1")`

Comment: @rawr. I have many variables so there will be more than four missing patterns.

Comment: @Laterow that's what I thought too, But they hard part I find is looking at each row and determining which missing pattern and thus which model to use from the list (without hard coding), and doing this in an aggregated row fashion.

Comment: `apply(newdata, 1, function(x) lm(reformulate(c(1, colnames(newdata)[!is.na(x)]), 'y')))`